# OracleDB: How to know a table row transaction CSN?

Tags: oracle

I want to know the last Transaction CSN in dupm of Oracle DB. And I wanna know how to delete this rows from dump or database from dump.

Comment: Do you mean the SCN (system change number)?  You can use LogMiner to look at the recent history of a table, and you can use RMAN to recover to a point in time.  But that information wouldn't be available in a simple export datapump dump file.  You'd need a tool that can use REDO information, which isn't a part of dump files.

Comment: I mean a Commit Sequence Number of transaction. I thank you, It's also helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer: CSN=SCN (the Commit Sequence Number (Oracle GoldenGate) is the same as System Change Number (Oracle DataBase).

**Information:** [SCN](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/oracle/oracle-system-change-number-an-introduction/)